# Url conversion in PHP

Tags: php

i have the following url in a html page-

```
/delete/Release 1
```

But when i am trying to print it it comes in following manner-

```
/delete/Release%201
```

**Can anyone suggest how to convert this hex value of %20 into a white space in PHP.**

Answer (score 3):

```
urldecode('/delete/Release%201');
```

Use [`urldecode`](http://php.net/urldecode).